# Stale Element after downloading file selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pyautogui

Trying to download videos after clicking a link. It works for the first page, but when the second link opens a new page, it says the element went stale **while** it is right-clicking it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import pyautogui

chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\"}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://portal.volleymetrics.hudl.com/#/auth/login')
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
driver.maximize_window()
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
user.send_keys('merin_sinha24')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
password.send_keys('password') #That is not the password
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-content"]/form/button').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#left-menu-container > div.left-menu-button-container-top > left-menu-button:nth-child(2)'))).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-matches-tabs"]/vm-tabs/div/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(9)
'''driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-matches-advanced-filters-text"]').click()
time.sleep(5)
start = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-matches-advanced-filters-container"]/div/ng-transclude/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/vm-input-box/div[2]/div/input')
start.send_keys('01102020')
end = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-matches-advanced-filters-container"]/div/ng-transclude/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/vm-input-box/div[2]/div/input')
end.send_keys('11012021')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-matches-advanced-filters-container"]/div/ng-transclude/div[3]/button[1]').click()'''
main_div = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="generic-table-two-row-group"]')
main_div = main_div[1]
links = main_div.find_elements_by_class_name('my-matches-table-row-container')
count = 0
while(len(links)!=count):
    links = main_div.find_elements_by_class_name('my-matches-table-row-container')
    link=links[count]
    count+=1
    link.click()
    parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
    all_windows = driver.window_handles
    child_window = [window for window in all_windows if window != parent_window][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(child_window)
    video = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'vm-match-video')))
    if not video:
        break
    else:
        div1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'vm-match-actions-directive')))
        divs2 = div1.find_elements_by_class_name('button-container')
        count2 = 0
        while(len(divs2)!=count2):
            divs2 = div1.find_elements_by_class_name('button-container')
            div=divs2[count2]
            count2 +=1
            if 'Video' and 'Download' in div.text:
                link = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                actionChains.context_click(link).perform()
                pyautogui.typewrite(['down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'enter'])
                time.sleep(5)
                pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
                driver.refresh()
                WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'vm-match-video')))
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-match-controls-column"]/div[3]/vm-match-actions/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/span[2]').click()
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"I Accept")]').click()
                    time.sleep(6)
                    break
                except:
                    break
            else:
                continue
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)
```

Comment: Hey, The way you are trying to click the elements after the driver.refresh() will make your elements stale.If the click also makes the page move to another you'd also have to get the div tags again.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Added the entire code for clarity. This is a new page which opens. The link loop, when it opens the second link..gives this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
links = main_div.find_elements_by_class_name('my-matches-table-row-container')
count = 0
while(len(links)!=count):
    links = main_div.find_elements_by_class_name('my-matches-table-row-container')
    link=links[count]
    count+=1
    link.click()
    parent_window = driver.current_window_handle
    all_windows = driver.window_handles
    child_window = [window for window in all_windows if window != parent_window][0]
    driver.switch_to.window(child_window)
    time.sleep(13)
    error = driver.find_element_by_class_name('video-message')
    if error.text == 'No video to display.':
        break
    else:
        div1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'vm-match-actions-directive')))
        divs2 = div1.find_elements_by_class_name('button-container')
        count2 = 0
        while(len(divs2)!=count2):
            divs2 = div1.find_elements_by_class_name('button-container')
            div=divs[count2] 
            count2+ =1
            if 'Video' and 'Download' in div.text:
                link = div.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
                actionChains.context_click(link)
                actionChains.perform()
                pyautogui.typewrite(['down', 'down', 'down', 'down', 'enter'])
                time.sleep(5)
                pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
                driver.refresh()
                time.sleep(15)
                try:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="portal-match-controls-column"]/div[3]/vm-match-actions/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/span[2]').click()
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"I Accept")]').click()
                    time.sleep(4)
                    break
                except:
                    break
            else:
                continue
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)
```

you should always find divs again , as you are clicking 'link' and this modifies the DOM, when ever DOM ( PAge html) is modified you have find all elements again as the previous reference is lost , this is why you get stale element

you can use driver.back() to navigate back

Comment: I have just included the whole code. The problem happens when the second link opens in a new window. It is a new window, the video is the first element to be found after I find the divs. The error suggests that the element goes stale WHILE right clicking the video to save target as.

Comment: @AbhishekRai you have to use same while loop logic for links also ,

Comment: I need to download the DVM file as well, if there is a video, that's whats started this issue, now it wont get the video from the second match.

Comment: Looks like while the video loads(takes 6-7 seconds), the div goes stale?

Comment: @AbhishekRai stale element happens when html changes , so if video loading changes html even if its .01 sec you will get stale element

Comment: Then why doesn't the first link fail? Only happens when the second link is opened? Don't know why it worked for first and not the second

Comment: @AbhishekRai then video loading is not changing the html , second link reloads html so you have to find all elements again

Comment: It's a new page, my friend. When the link is clicked, a new tab is opened. I don't do anything on the page. It goes stale while the page is opening, for the first time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227222/discussion-between-abhishek-rai-and-pdhide).